# Avoid plain sign-ups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a passwordless phone OTP authentication flow in Amazon Cognito. According to a blog from AWS, a user is automatically signed up (added to user pool) when they input their phone number.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/

The problem with this is that a single client can input multiple phone numbers thus multiple sign ups, leading to an increase in Monthly Active Users (MAU) and subsequently higher costs in Amazon Cognito. How can I avoid this scenario?

I was thinking of adding captcha for pre sign-ups and integrating waf for rate limiting. Is this a good solution?